# Finding the inverse laplace transform of $s$

Tags: laplace-transform

How do I find the inverse laplace transform of $s$, i.e. $$L^{-1}\{s\}=\ ?$$

Answer (score 10):

$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{s\}=\delta'(t)$.
More generally:

> $\forall n\in\mathbb{Z},~\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{s^n\}=\delta^{(n)}(t)$.

Comment: Sorry this might be a stupid question, but what is this function $\delta (t)$? This inverse transform doesn't seem to appear on tables?

Answer (score 2):

One would have a hard time finding such a function since Laplace transforms of functions go to zero at infinity and Laplace transforms of measures are bounded.