# Inverse Laplace Transform of $\frac{s^2+2s+2}{s+1}$

Tags: laplace-transform

I want detailed steps of this if anyone can help.

Comment: Try doing polynomial division to simplify the fraction.

Comment: @user136837 Is this formatting ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{s^2+2s+2}{s+1}=\frac{(s+1)^2+1}{s+1}=s+1+\frac1{s+1}$$

Now, can you set the proper value of $a$ in $$L\{e^{at}\}=\frac1{s-a}$$

Set $c=0$ in $$L\{\delta(t-c)\}=e^{-cs}$$

Finally use [Finding the inverse laplace transform of $s$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414615/finding-the-inverse-laplace-transform-of-s)

Comment: Is that the whole answer??

Comment: @imranfat, I've just completed .

Comment: Your link is "closed" and I though when doing an inverse laplace we are supposed to get t-terms back?

Comment: @imranfat, but there is one valid answer, I believe

Comment: makes sense, just not used to inverses laplace of plain polynomial terms since that is kind of...rare?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$\frac{s^2 + 2s + 2}{s + 1}  = \frac{(s + 1)^2 + 1}{s + 1} = s + 1 + \frac{1}{s + 1}$$

Comment: Please use latex.